# Database design: Send the ID or the Value in a relationship

Tags: database, database-design

this is a design question.

Imagine this, I have two tables.

```
|user|
------
|id|
|username|
|team_id|

|team|
------
|id|
|name|
```

So when receiving a `POST /users`

Should I send

```
{
   "username": "newUser",
   "name": "myTeam" /
}
```

Get the team id first or includes if using ORMs

or

```
{
   "username": "newUser",
   "team_id": 1 // references the "myTeam"
}
```

Insert it directly and if the team_id doesn't exists fail

Which one is the best and why?

This is just an example with only one relationship and it could happen that the user table has a lot of relationships

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which data is important and which isn't. If your front end wants to show the name of the team then send the name of the team or if it just wants to show the id then just send the id.

In my opinion, you should send the name because it will be much more clear to the user than just the id.

Comment: Which ORM are you using?